# jquery validate, dynamically binding form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to dynamically bind validation on an ajax response for some address validation forms.  I have tried a few things, but can't seem to get this working.  Here's what I got so far any help is appeciated, all the console.log's are working.

```
 $('#profileAddresses form').each(function() {
            console.log('each');
            var _id = $(this).prop('id');
            var _idNum = _id.split('-');
            var _input = _idNum[1];
            var line1 = 'profile' + _input + 'Line1';
            var city = 'profile' + _input + 'City';
            var state = 'profile' + _input + 'State';
            var zip = 'profile' + _input + 'Zip';
            var country = 'profile' + _input + 'Country';
            $(this).validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                errorClass: 'error',
                errorElement: 'div',
                onfocusout: false,
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertBefore(element);
                },
                rules: {
                    line1: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    city: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    state: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    zip: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    country: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    line1: {
                        required: 'Please enter a street address.'
                    },
                    city: {
                        required: 'Please select a city.'
                    },
                    state: {
                        required: 'Please select a state.'
                    },
                    zip: {
                        required: 'Please enter a zip code.',
                        minlengh: 'Pleaes enter a valid zip code.'
                    },
                    country: {
                        required: 'Please select a country.'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: @Sparky thanks for taking time to edit tags and not respond to the question.  Also, you removed validation which has everything to do with this question and added ajax which has nothing to do with the issue.  Amateur Hour, no idea how spammers like you accumulate reputation points.

Comment: Because I've answered 650 questions about [tag:jquery-validate]... that's how.  I'm under no obligation to help any single particular user so I'm really sorry your feelings got hurt by me skipping over yours.   Removed [tag:validation] tag because it's already tagged with [tag:jquery-validate].  (Take note of [how few](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate+validation) of the 4,000 jQuery Validate questions are tagged with both.)  Tagged with `ajax` because you said, _"I am trying to dynamically bind validation on an **ajax response**"_.  Having a bad day?

Comment: It's just a retag. Also, I don't think you know what a spammer is. Also, @Sparky is right, no one is obligated to answer your question, even if they edited it.

Comment: I wasn't having a bad day and do appreciate help. But to me just making unhelpful edits and comments to increase your reputation points is a waste of everyones time.

Comment: also you're right, no one is ever obligated to help but thankfully someone that actually understands web development was able to help me out with this quick question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work incase someone else runs into this problem, just set the validation on the form and then add the rules to the input.  I added a class to each so I could change the required message or requirements.

```
 $('#profileAddresses form').each(function() {
            $(this).validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                errorClass: 'error',
                errorElement: 'div',
                onfocusout: false,
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertBefore(element);
                }
            });
            var _id = $(this).prop('id');
            $('#' + _id + ' input').each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass('profileAddressZip')) {
                    $(this).rules('add', {
                        required: true,
                        messages: {
                            required: 'Required msg.'
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        });
```